# Loop through AnyObject Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My  data contains user data of various  values (which I can parse out)  then  balances for each user  in  a  number of  currencies.

I can parse out the user data.  For example:

```
if let add2 = parsed["address"] as? String {
    println("Alert: \(add2)")
}
```

I can get the lists of balances:

```
if let findbalances = parsed["balances"]{    
           println("find the balances: \(findbalances)")
```

and I can get the individual values:

```
var balance11:Double = findbalances[0]["available_amount"] as! Double/100

var curr11:String = findbalances[0]["currency"] as! String
```

The array is `AnyObject`.  If I try:

```
for currency in findbalances {
```

I get

> Type AnyObject  does not conform to Sequence

So then I tried to downcast it to `String`:

```
if let findbalances = parsed["balances"] as? String {
for currency in findbalances {
```

and my output is blank.

Yet I know the values are there.

I am stumped; how do you loop through an `AnyObject` Array in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're close. In your code "for currency in findbalances {", you should know that currency is a dictionary, not the currency. Were you looking for something like this?

```
for balance in findbalances as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
    let currency = balance["currency"] as! String
    //do something with currency
}
```

Comment: `as` should be `as!` or `as?`

Comment: I think that's only the case if findbalances is an optional right? If it's a ! already, the "as" should work? I'm assuming it's not an optional since he's pulling data directly like he was... I guess in that case, he wouldn't need the "as [[String: AnyObject]]" at all.

Comment: since Swift 1.2, `as` has to be either `as!` or `as?`.

Comment: Ok, fixed it. @techguy, note if the compiler complains you may be able to remove the "as" portion from the findbalances if it was originally defined properly.

Comment: @Jaconbson not quite – casts that _aren’t guaranteed at compile time to succeed_ (such as `AnyObject` to something else) have to be `as[?!]`.  But some casts are guaranteed at compile time to work every time (such as the other way – something else to `AnyObject`) and they can still be `as`

Comment: Agree with @AirspeedVelocity, in 1.2 I don't have to put !? next to every "as" statement but many more require it.

Comment: TravisM  you are  champion!!!    I've spent all day trying to  work this out and you have it in  half an hour!